# Hover set timeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `display:none` if user hovers my banner for 500ms, but the following JQuery code is not working. Where is mistake?

```
$('.banner').hover(function() {

      setTimeout(function(){

      $(this).css('display','none');

    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: *I want to display:none if user hover it with 500 miliseconds.* What does that mean? Hovering *for* 500 ms? In any case, `this` inside the callback refers to `window`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` inside your `setTimeout` does not refer to the `this` in the `hover` function. You can cache the `this` in your `hover` function so that it can be used in the `setTimeout` function:

```
$('.banner').hover(function() {

      var $this = $(this);

      setTimeout(function(){

          $this.css('display','none');

    }, 500);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hVejj/

**Update**

```
var timer;
$('.banner').hover(function() {

      var $this = $(this);

      timer = setTimeout(function(){

          $this.css('display','none');

    }, 500);
},
function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Here is a demo for this update: http://jsfiddle.net/hVejj/1/

Comment: Thanks Jasper, that works. But actually, what I want to do is, if user is hovering banner for 500 miliseconds. Not fire after too fast hover and mouseout.

Comment: @user198989 Check-out my update, it should do the trick for ya. The functionality you want is called `hoverIntent` and there is a plugin for it but my update is the basic idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass `$(this)` like that in an anonymous function.  Set it to a variable instead

```
$('.banner').hover(function() {

    var banner = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {

        banner.css('display', 'none');

    }, 500);


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkjn6/

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to hide the banner when you've hovered over it for 500ms, then you need to save a reference to the DOM element being hidden.  You probably also want to clear the timer if you've stopped hovering before the timeout fires.  You'll need the signature that takes an in AND out handler separately.  Store the timer handle and clear it when you stop hovering if it hasn't already expired.

```
var hoverTimer = null;
$('.banner').hover(function() { 
   var $banner = $(this);
   hoverTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                     hoverTimer = null;
                     $banner.css('display','none');
                }, 500); 
}, function() {
   if (hoverTimer) {
      clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
   }
   hoverTimer = null;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the callback function access to the right `this` variable:

```
$('.banner').hover(function() {
      var temp = this;
      setTimeout(function(){
      temp.css('display','none');
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will hide the banner after the user hovers for more than 500 ms:

```
var timeout;
$('.banner').hover(
    var banner = $(this);

    // Hover In
    function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() { banner.hide(); }, 500);
    },
    // Hover Out
    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.banner').hover(function() {
  var me = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    me.css('display','none');
  }, 500);
});
```

The *this* variable changes meaning based on scope.  Once inside the the function in the *setTimeout()* call *this* no longer refers to the *.banner* element.

So you need to "save" that reference so you can use in the function in the *setTimeout()* call.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do what I think, something like this should make it work:

```
var tmp_abort
$('.banner').mouseenter(function() {
    tmp_abort=setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).css('display','none');
    }, 500);
});   

$('.banner').mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(tmp_abort)
});
```

`

Comment: You don't have to select `.banner` twice, you can chain the calls: $('.banner').mouseenter().mouseleave();`. Welcome to stackoverflow too!